# XmlNode could not be found error in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2013

I am making a weather app using C# in Visual Studio 2013.I have used the namespace `System.Xml` and also added the reference of `System.Xml.XmlNode` using the object browser.

But still when I am trying to use the namespace `XmlNode` it is showing the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'XmlNode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Am I using any broken reference?
And how to rectify this error?

Comment: `XmlNode` is a type. The namespace is `System.Xml` and the assembly is `System.Xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx it requires namespace `System.Xml` in `System.Xml.dll` assembly.

So first add a reference to `System.Xml.dll` and then add the following `using` statement in your code:

```
 using System.Xml;
```

Comment: How to add a reference to System.Xml.dll??I have already added a reference of System.Xml to my project using the object browser.

Comment: thanks very much.I have tried it...But it doesn't seem to work.I guess I figured it out that XmlNode type doesn't have a support in windows store apps..can you tell me about a substitution of XmlNode class for windows Store app??how to select a particular node from a XmlNodeList without using the XmlNode class type??

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your project references the System.Xml.dll assembly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your assembly references System.Xml.dll
2. Make sure to put `using System.Xml;` in the top of the `.cs` file